# How to get NodeType information from a controller

Tags: neoscms

How could I get NodeType information from within a controller? E.g., for checking access rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you are asking for:

You can get access of a nodes property within a controller (e.g. for an extension) like this:

$myOwnProperty = $this->request->getInternalArgument('__myOwnProperty');

"myOwnProperty" has to be defined for a nodetype in Configuration\Settings.yaml

The internal argument gets two underscores before the property name.

Comment: Don't you mean in `NodeTypes.yaml`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, of course. They have to be defined in the 'NodeTypes.yaml'